# (Cross compile) How to specify the location of libraries for ld in Makefile?

Tags: make, cross-compilation, ld

I am compiling pciutils (but it's not important, it could be another source code) with a gcc ARM version.

When I compile, the process stops because it cannot find the required libraries:

```
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lz
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lresolv
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lc
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.2/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:103: recipe for target 'lspci' failed
make: *** [lspci] Error 1
```

But, for example, **crt1.o** can be found in three directories:

```
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/overo-tcbootstrap/usr/lib/crt1.o
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/overo/usr/lib/crt1.o
/home/simo/development/gcc-armhf-yocto-sysroot/sysroots/overo/usr/include/glibc-locale-internal-cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crt1.o
```

How can I avoid this issue ?
It could be useful also for other source codes (since I have to compile a few sets of).

Thank you.

Comment: Where did the `Makefile` come from?

Comment: from the source code of pciutils (I am trying to compile version 3.3.1 from https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/utils/pciutils/) and I modified the CROSS_COMPILE flag and added the required flags for sysroot and include directories of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in makefiles you can add `-L/path/to/lib` to the linker-flags. However I dont know if this is a good solution for your concrete problem.